# merge rows data in tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a table with one column that include this data

```
Data
'a'
'b'
'c'
'd'
'e'
'f'
```

How can I get combine Data column data in one varchar with cte?

```
result : 'abcdef'
```

Comment: Why does it have to be with a CTE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could quite simply do it using

```
SELECT '' + [Data] 
FROM Table1
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/710c0/9)